# get end user tokens for eBay restful in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ebay-api

currently I am using eBay Trading API with Python. Thanks to: https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python

I used https://github.com/luke-dixon/django-ebay-accounts to get tokens for user.

Now, I would like to use Restful API (https://developer.ebay.com/docs#Acc). I don't think I can use tokens I have already. So, I managed thanks to [Getting an Ebay OAuth Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046855/getting-an-ebay-oauth-token) get one. But I think I missing something, because during the process I cannot include info for user (name/password), so, for example `https://api.ebay.com/sell/fulfillment/v1/order?limit=10` returns:

```
{
  "errors": [{
    "errorId": 1100,
    "domain": "ACCESS",
    "category": "REQUEST",
    "message": "Access denied",
    "longMessage": "Insufficient permissions to fulfill the request."
  }]
}
```

Any idea how can I get a token for the user?

Just snippet of code to make things more clear:

```
AppSettings = {
            'app_id': EBAY_PRODUCTION_APPID,
            'app_secret': EBAY_PRODUCTION_CERTID,
            'dev_id': EBAY_PRODUCTION_DEVID, 
            'ruName': EBAY_PRODUCTION_RU_NAME 
        }
authHeaderData = AppSettings['app_id'] + ':' + AppSettings['app_secret']
        encodedAuthHeader = base64.b64encode(authHeaderData.encode())

        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization": "Basic ".encode() + encodedAuthHeader
        }
body = {
            "grant_type": "client_credentials",
            "redirect_uri": settings.EBAY_PRODUCTION_RU_NAME,
            "scope": "https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope"
        }

        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(body)

        tokenURL = "https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token"

        response = requests.post(tokenURL, headers=headers, data=body)
        authDict = response.json()
```

So the request to run I need is:

```
r = requests.get("https://api.ebay.com/sell/fulfillment/v1/order?limit=10",
                         headers={"Authorization": "{}".format(authDict['access_token']),
                                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                  "X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID": "EBAY_UK",
                                  "Accept": "application/json"
                                  })
```

Comment: "in place of a username/passwd" ? Sorry, I got confused. What part of the code are you reffering to?

Comment: disregard that comment.  I was confused :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting eBay Access Token (Exchanging auth token) with python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649316/getting-ebay-access-token-exchanging-auth-token-with-python-requests)

Comment: **Definitely** not a duplicate of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649316/getting-ebay-access-token-exchanging-auth-token-with-python-requests) question... Getting an access token and trying to use an access token are two completely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API Explore @ developer.ebay.com has description of HTTP Headers for each RestFul API. E.G. Fulfillment API - getOrdres:

HTTP Headers
Authorization:Bearer <OAUTH_token>
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json

Sample code:

```
import requests,json

headers = {
 
    "Authorization": "Bearer Type_Your_Token_here_or_Paste_IF_too_long",
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
}

EndPoint = "https://api.ebay.com/sell/fulfillment/v1/order?filter=orderfulfillmentstatus:%7BNOT_STARTED|IN_PROGRESS%7D"

response = requests.get(EndPoint,headers = headers)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/rest-request-components.html), I believe you are supposed to use the following authorization header:

```
headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Where the `USER_ACCESS_TOKEN` is the massive token generated on [this](https://developer.ebay.com/my/auth/?env=sandbox&index=0&auth_type=oauth) page.

It looks something like this:

```
'v^1.1#i^1#p^3#f^0#I^3#r^0#t^ ...
...
...
...
... bfxr8BJtphi2M/oo2xpYo2hiMWxmZt4fVzS7qe2tMXUSAAA='
```

The `Authorization` you are using is for requests that aren't linked to a specific user account (search results, meta data for items, etc.).  To make requests that are for specific users (eg. orders or inventory updates), you have to get their permission via their `USER_ACCESS_TOKEN`.

If you need help getting the `USER_ACCESS_TOKEN` let me know and I'll update.

**Note** that I have been trying to do the same thing that you are doing for about 6 hours now, and still haven't figured it out, so I am not confident in this answer.

Hope this helps.  If you do figure it out, you should post an answer so others can too (ie myself xD).

eBay definitely wins the **gold metal** for *worst api docs in the history of api docs*...

Comment: thanks for your comment. I will give another try to solve this on Monday. I will post my results.

Comment: I am not sure if you were able to resolve the issue. longMessage": "Insufficient permissions to fulfill the request." comes up if the tokens do not have the correct scope when the authorization_code grant was requested.

Comment: Have you guys gotten this to work?  The API documents are a sh!tstorm of awful.  I've managed to fix some of the default-failing examples ebay presents but I'm also hitting the  "Insufficient permissions to fulfill the request" error

Comment: @carlcrott I have.  If you ask a separate question I can help you there.  Just remember to tag me so I can see it

Comment: @reinstate-monica I believe I tagged you in it. As a backup https://stackoverflow.com/q/61706632/365798

Comment: @SenthilkumarGopal  can you advise i keep getting 





{'error': 'invalid_client', 'error_description': 'client authentication failed'}

Comment: @sunnybabau Sure, can I have the link to your question?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Thank you sir. Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63063985/ebay-token-and-getdealitems-api-call-issue

Comment: @sunnybabau Please refer to the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63063985/ebay-token-and-getdealitems-api-call-issue/63084190#63084190. Hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`https://newbedev.com/ebay-oauth-token-and-refresh-tokens` has introduced eBay OAuth token much better than eBay.

By the way, `"grant_type": "client_credentials"` is only valid for clients who can on have one scope. `https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope`.

A shortcut to get your code run: the **refresh token** is actually the token you have for standard API, which is valid for 18 months. With a refresh token, you can get token without getting the annoying "authorization code" via user consent.

In short, please use **refresh token** to get **user access token** for the restful API.

Hope the above helps.