# What does a completed "Authorization Code Grant Flow" look like for ebays OAuth2 API

Tags: oauth-2.0, ebay-api

Given that ebays own example API docs break...

Im hoping for an example of sequential code which can be run, ultimately granting a codified application authorization token.

EDIT:

The original motivation of this post was to use the createItemDraft API.

Turns out you need to be some special invite-only Ebay partner to do this.

Comment: @reinstate-monica I believe you might be able to help

Comment: Follow this link to learn how to ask good questions. I am voting to close this question as you have shown no effort, no code and no problem to answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The eBay docs are *technically* correct and show you how it works, but quite difficult to understand.  What code have you tried?  It would be much easier to help if you show broken code that I can fix.