# Ebay Token and GetDealItems API Call Issue

Tags: python, ebay-api

I'm trying to access GetDealItems API and i have a nightmare to get this working. Even though I use the valid `client_id','client_secret','ruName'` i keep getting

```
{'error': 'invalid_client', 'error_description': 'client authentication failed'}
```

below is the ebay doc

```
https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/deal/resources/deal_item/methods/getDealItems
```

I guess i need to use this scope and url in my request

```
scopes:'https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.deal' and the 
url='https://api.ebay.com/buy/deal/v1/deal_item?limit=1000'
```

Please see below my Python code.

```
import requests, urllib, base64

def getAuthToken():
    AppSettings = {
          'client_id':'xxxx7c8ec878c-c80c4c69',
          'client_secret':'xxxx56db-4b4a-97b4-fad2',
          'ruName':'xxxxx-gscrcsrtj'}

    authHeaderData = AppSettings['client_id'] + ':' + AppSettings['client_secret']
    encodedAuthHeader = base64.b64encode(str.encode(authHeaderData))

    headers = {
          "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
          "Authorization" : "Bearer " + str(encodedAuthHeader)
          }

    body= {
          "grant_type" : "client_credentials",
          "redirect_uri" : AppSettings['ruName'],
          "scope" : "https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.deal"
      }

    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(body)

    tokenURL = "https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token"

    response = requests.post(tokenURL, headers=headers, data=data) 
    return response.json()


response = getAuthToken()
print(response)
response['access_token'] #access keys as required
response['error_description'] #if errors
```

Comment: @ReinstateMonica sir can you please advise on this

Comment: Have you tried using postman (or client of your choice) to get a token? Have you verified that your client credentials are current and correct? Have you verified that your client id is setup for that scope?

Comment: client id's r correct and regarding scope how do we setup for that? isnt that something we call with that scope parameter?

Comment: Scopes are assigned when you generate your application keys: https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-scopes.html

Comment: correct so how do we get this deals specific scope granted?

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious problem I see is that you are using `Bearer` when you should be using `Basic` in your `Authorization` header.

Also, You are urlencoding your **`redirect_url`** when you pass the entire dictionary into `urlencode`.  The docs say you are supposed to urlencode the `scope` parameter, but honestly, I never encode the scope and it still works for me.

Here is your modified code, with a few formatting changes:

```
import requests, urllib, base64

client_id='xxxx7c8ec878c-c80c4c69'
client_secret='xxxx56db-4b4a-97b4-fad2'
ruName='xxxxx-gscrcsrtj'

scope = urllib.parse.quote('https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.deal')

def basic_token(key, secret):
    return 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode((key + ':' + secret).encode()).decode()

def getAuthToken():

    headers = {
        "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization" : basic_token(client_id, client_secret)
    }

    data = (
        'grant_type=client_credentials&'
        f'redirect_uri={ruName}&'
        f'scope={scope}'
    )

    tokenURL = "https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token"

    response = requests.post(tokenURL, headers=headers, data=data)
    return response.json()
```

### Update:

I think you need to use the **[`authorization_code`](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-scopes.html)** grant instead of **`client_credentials`**.

To use the `authorization_code` grant, modify your body to look like this:

```
data = (
    'grant_type=authorization_code&'
    f'code={authorization_code}&'
    f'redirect_uri={ruName}&'
    f'scope={scope}'
)
```

Also, you will need to follow your **"redirect url"** to get the actual authorization code.  Execute the following:

```
redirect_url = (
    'https://auth.ebay.com/oauth2/authorize?'
    f'client_id={client_id}&'
    f'response_type=code&'
    f'redirect_uri={ruName}&'
    f'scope={scope}'
)
print(redirect_url)
```

Copy/paste the url from stdout, follow the link, and click "accept", then you will be redirected to a url that looks like this:

```
https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ThirdPartyAuthSucessFailure&isAuthSuccessful=true&code=<authorization code here>&expires_in=299
```

Copy/paste the authorization code into your code, then see if it works.

Realistically, eBay expects you to automate this within your application using a server, but it doesn't make sense for you to go through the trouble if you are building an app for personal use.

Comment: so i just added  r = response.json() and then print(r) and i get "{'error': 'invalid_request', 'error_description': 'request is missing a required parameter or malformed.'}" Is it because of buy.deal scope on my account? if yes, how do i get that scope??

Comment: @sunnybabau  I think the problem is with the `client_credentials` grant, because the `buy.deal` scope isn't specified under the [allowed scopes](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-scopes.html) for client credentials.  I'll update to walk you through using the `authorization_code` grant flow.

Comment: sadly i get this after clicking on the redirect_url "{"error_id":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"The OAuth client was not found.","http_status_code":401}"

Comment: @sunnybabau Try using the redirect url they give you at the [application keys](https://developer.ebay.com/my/keys) dashboard.

Comment: I appreciate all the help.. so i took the successful "code=" from UI and copy and replaced code={authorization_code} and yet i get "{'error': 'invalid_request', 'error_description': 'request is missing a required parameter or malformed.'}"

Comment: Do you think I should activate eBay premium support and get this solved please?

Comment: @sunnybabau Are you using production keys?  According to the [Buy API](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/deal/static/overview.html): *"The use of eBay’s Buy APIs in production is intended for eBay partners only."*  This might be why you are getting errors, also, I doubt premium support would help if this were the case.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't tell you this earlier.  I don't have experience with the Buy API specifically.

Comment: No problem thank you for all the support. Also, was curious if you can provide ur expert guidance on this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63079625/python-xml-parse-and-getelementsbytagname

Answer (score 0):

GetDealItems API uses client_credentials grant as evident from the [docs](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/deal/resources/deal_item/methods/getDealItems)

[image]

The authorization should be using client_id and secret as described in getting [access tokens](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-client-credentials-grant.html)

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-H 'Authorization: Basic UkVTVFRlc3...wZi1hOGZhLTI4MmY=' \
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.ebay.com%2Foauth%2Fapi_scope%2Fbuy.deal'
```

Note: if the error is `client_authorization_failed`, ensure that the correct Keyset for production is used for production. Also ensure that the keyset is also enabled for `Oauth`

**Finally, you can use/refer to the official python SDK as well [here](https://github.com/eBay/ebay-oauth-python-client/blob/master/oauthclient/oauth2api.py#L60)**

A simple way to check if the particular scope, in this case `https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.deal` is even allowed for this app, is to navigate to the keyset page under [Keys link](https://developer.ebay.com/my/keys#) and click on "Oauth scopes" under the keyset which details the scopes allowed and their purpose. If the application is once authorized for buy.deal, then the scope will appear there.

[image]

**UPDATE**

GetDeals API is restricted in Production for authorized applications only. Please reach out to the eBay developer program as provided in the link on the page below.

https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/deal/overview.html#API

[image]

Comment: Thanks you. So i have tried with both Basic <B64-encoded_oauth_credentials> Base64 encode the following: <client_id>:<client_secret> and as well as Basic <Oauth> keyset for production and nothing seem to work??

Comment: @sunnybabau I believe your app is not authorized for buy.deal scope as it needs explicit agreements. I have edited my answer above with more details.